# Patching an existing js function but still show up

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-11

I use odoo11.
I have a requirement that is to change the confirm content when click delete.

I found this from a js file called `basic_controller.js` on web addons

```js
var BasicController = AbstractController.extend(FieldManagerMixin, {
...
    _deleteRecords: function (ids) {
        var self = this;
        function doIt() {
            return self.model
                .deleteRecords(ids, self.modelName)
                .then(self._onDeletedRecords.bind(self, ids));
        }
        if (this.confirmOnDelete) {
            Dialog.confirm(this, _t("Are you sure you want to delete this record ?"), {
                confirm_callback: doIt,
            });
        } else {
            doIt();
        }
    },
...
```

And I found the patching method from [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/javascript_reference.html#patching-an-existing-class).
I write a new js file to patch it like this.

```js
BasicController.include({
    _deleteRecords: function (ids) {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        var self = this;
        function doIt() {
            return self.model.deleteRecords(ids, self.modelName).then(self._onDeletedRecords.bind(self, ids));
        }
        if (this.confirmOnDelete) {
            Dialog.confirm(this, _t("rewrite content?"), {
                confirm_callback: doIt,
            });
        } else {
            doIt();
        }
    },

})
```

It will show my content but after confirm or cancel.
The origin one will follow up.

[image]

How can I replace the origin one totally?

Comment: If this js code is used only to change the translated value, try to add a translation file (in your language) to override the original.

Comment: I need some if-else statements. So only add translation is not match my requirement. thx for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you overwrite the function's entire content, then you don't need to call `this._super.apply(this, arguments);`
Currently, you are creating two dialogs.

JS File

```
odoo.define('mytest.field', function (require) {
'use strict';

var basic_fields = require('web.BasicController');
var Dialog = require('web.Dialog');
var core = require('web.core');

var _t = core._t;

var FieldClearbit = basic_fields.include({
    _deleteRecords: function (ids) {
        var self = this;
        function doIt() {
            return self.model.deleteRecords(ids, self.modelName).then(self._onDeletedRecords.bind(self, ids));
        }
        if (this.confirmOnDelete) {
            Dialog.confirm(this, _t("rewrite content?"), {
                confirm_callback: doIt,
            });
        } else {
            doIt();
        }
    },

})

});
```

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template id="assets_backend" name="Rdets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/mytest/static/src/js/test.js" />
        </xpath>
    </template>

</odoo>
```

Try enabling assets debugging to regenerate web assets.
Most likely, you need to upgrade your module to changes to apply.

Comment: I try your method.  And it won't replace the original.