# How to get value through rpc query?

Tags: javascript, odoo, rpc, odoo-11

I have written a JS code to replace an existing function,
here is [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63050344/patching-an-existing-js-function-but-still-show-up?noredirect=1#comment111512436_63050344).

I have successfully replaced it.
And now I want to judge the user whether has authentication to delete the record or not.
I don't want to control it by `ir.model.access` or rewrite the unlink method, which can not do something else in advance.

The system may delete the record or sent a mail to the admin according to the user's level.
Then I need to get a result from RPC query.

```js
_admin_check: function(){
        var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(url);
        var id = urlParams.get('id');
        var uid = odoo.session_info.uid;
        return rpc.query({
            model: 'res.users',
            method: 'check_administration',
            args: [id,uid],
        }).then(function (result) {
            console.log(result)
            return result // how to actually return result
        });

    },
```

the RPC function which I call.

```py
    def check_administration(self,uid):
        groups = self.env['res.groups']
        bs_manager = []
        lv8 = groups.search([('name', '=', 'level 8')]).users.ids
        lv7 = groups.search([('name', '=', 'level 7')]).users.ids
        admin = groups.search([('name', '=', 'setting')]).users.ids
        bs_manager = [r for r in admin if r not in bs_manager]
        bs_manager += [r for r in lv8 if r not in bs_manager]
        bs_manager += [r for r in lv7 if r not in bs_manager]
        if uid not in bs_manager:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

then I call this function (`_admin_check`) during delete confirmation.

```js
if (this.confirmOnDelete) {
    var is_admin = self._admin_check();
    if(is_admin){
        Dialog.confirm(this, _t("Are you sure you want to delete this record ?"), {
            confirm_callback: doIt,
        });
    }
    else{
        Dialog.confirm(this, _t("You are not allow to delete this record. Sysyem will send a request to administrators. "), {
            confirm_callback: self.send_delete_request(),
        });
    }
} else {
    doIt();
}
```

I'm sure the console can get the result is true or false.

[image]

But it seems that can not get by variable `is_admin` .
[image]

How can I get it by rpc query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are seems no way to return value through RPC,
then I try to use RPC directly in my confirmation.

```py
if (this.confirmOnDelete) {
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(url);
    var id = urlParams.get('id');
    var uid = odoo.session_info.uid;
    rpc.query({
        model: 'res.users',
        method: 'check_administration',
        args: [id,uid],
    }).then(function (result) {
        if(result){
            Dialog.confirm(this, _t("Are you sure you want to delete this record ?"), {
                confirm_callback: doIt,
            });
        }
        else{
            Dialog.confirm(this, _t("You are not allow to delete this record. Sysyem will send a request to administrators."), {
                confirm_callback: self.send_delete_request(),
            });
        }
    });
}
```